# How to compare two unsigned integers (uint8_t) in c

Tags: c, pointers, compare, unsigned-integer

I have two uint8_t pointers in my program and I want to compare the values of those. I don't have good idea to deal with unsigned ints. Here is my code

```
static void bacast_signed_message()
{
  uint8_t *M = malloc(MAX_M_LEN*sizeof(uint8_t));//uint8_t M[MAX_M_LEN];//uint8_t *M;
  int M_len = MAX_M_LEN;;

  uint8_t *C = malloc((2*KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN + 1 + MAX_M_LEN + HMAC_LEN)*sizeof(uint8_t));   
  int C_len; 
  //uint8_t C[2*KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN + 1 + MAX_M_LEN + HMAC_LEN]; 

  uint8_t *dM = malloc(MAX_M_LEN*sizeof(uint8_t));  //uint8_t dM[MAX_M_LEN];
  int dM_len = MAX_M_LEN;

  random_data(M, MAX_M_LEN);

  printf("C before encrypt %p\n",*C);
  printf("M before encrypt %p\n",*M);
  printf("dM before encrypt %p\n",*dM);

  C_len = encrypt(C, (2*KEYDIGITS*NN_DIGIT_LEN + 1 + M_len + HMAC_LEN), M, M_len, &pbkey_alice);
  //encrypt(uint8_t *C, int C_len, uint8_t *M, int M_len, Point *PublicKey);

  printf("C after encrypt %p\n",*C);
  printf("M after encrypt %p\n",*M);
  printf("dM after encrypt %p\n",*dM);

  dM_len = decrypt(dM, dM_len, C, C_len, prKey_alice);   
  //decrypt(uint8_t *M, int M_len, uint8_t *C, int C_len, NN_DIGIT *d);

  printf("C after decrypt %p\n",*C);
  printf("M after decrypt %p\n",*M);
  printf("dM after decrypt %p\n",*dM);

  printf("C_len = %i , M_len = %i\n",C_len,M_len);

  if (dM == M){printf("Works\n");}
  else{printf("Not Works\n");}
}
```

and this is the out put I got

```
C before encrypt 0x40
M before encrypt 0x28
dM before encrypt 0x70
C after encrypt 0x4
M after encrypt 0x28
dM after encrypt 0x70
C after decrypt 0x4
M after decrypt 0x28
dM after decrypt 0x28
C_len = 102 , M_len = 41
Not Works
```

And if I changed private_key(no change of public key) then It looks like  this

```
C before encrypt 0x40
M before encrypt 0x28
dM before encrypt 0x70
C after encrypt 0x4
M after encrypt 0x28
dM after encrypt 0x70
C after decrypt 0x4
M after decrypt 0x28
dM after decrypt 0x70
C_len = 102 , M_len = 41
Not Works
```

That mean dM has not changed no. But I am not sure about this. If I use %u instead of %p it will give me totally different answers(it says if we use %u it'll convert to decimal). Please give me some advice, and tell me whats wrong  with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That code is painful to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Possible ways to understand your question

Your code `if (dM == M)` currently compares *pointers*. So you're currently checking whether or not the two pointers indicate the same chunk of memory.

Your question title suggests that you want to compare single numbers. After all, an `uint8_t` is just a single number in the range 0 - 255. If you have pointers to such numbers, you'd have to *dereference* them to get at the actual numbers, like `if (*dM == *M)`.

But your code suggests that you actually want to compare memory regions. Dereferencing a pointer to an array is the same as accessing the first element of the array (i.e. the same as `if (dM[0] == M[0])`), which probably is not what you want.

## Comparing memory regions

You can use [`memcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp) to compare the content of memory regions:

```
if (dM_len == M_len && memcmp(dM, M, dM_len) == 0)
```

This means “if the lengths are the same, and the content of the two memory regions is the same as well”. If the result of `memcmp` is nonzero, its sign provides information as to which value is considered greater.

## Printing

Note that the `%p` in your `printf` calls is probably wrong: `%p` is for printing *pointers*, but as you're dereferencing them in the function call, you're actually printing *values*. So `%u` is much more suitable. If you want to print the content of e.g. `M`, you'll have to use a loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i != M_len; ++i) {
  if (i%32 == 0 && i != 0) printf("\n"); /* wrap lines */
  printf("%02x", M[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

This will print a hexadecimal representation of your data, with 32 bytes (= 64 hexadecimal digits) per line. The `%02x` format instructs `printf` to allways use two digits for every byte, padding with zero as required.

Answer (score 2):

There are specific macros for printing the "stdint.h" types. For instance:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

...
uint8_t u8 = 5;
printf("%"PRIu8, u8); // unsigned 
printf("%"PRIx8, u8); // hexadecimal
```

Hence you should change e.g:

```
printf("C after decrypt %p\n",*C);
```

to

```
printf("C after decrypt %"PRIu8"\n",*C);
```

Note that `%p` is for printing pointers (addresses), and not the-value-pointed-to. And since you de-reference `C` you probably are not getting the results you want.